# Where is the new docker hub api documentation?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

[Since docker 1.8](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/api/docker-io_api/) you can see that:

> This API is deprecated as of 1.7. To view the old version, see the Docker Hub API in the 1.7 documentation.

But when I look at the [new documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/) There is nothing about the API access.

I thought it was based on [Docker Trusted Registry](https://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/overview/) but I can't make it work.

Commands like that works: `curl -k https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/ubuntu/tags` but it's v1 deprecated api.

Comment: Look left down --> docs archive

Comment: This leads to the deprecated api, but I'm looking for the up to date api

Answer (score 10, accepted):

V1 is deprecated. You can find the latest documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

Here is a couple of example scripts using the api:

- For a user account: https://gist.github.com/kizbitz/e59f95f7557b4bbb8bf2
- For an organization account: https://gist.github.com/kizbitz/175be06d0fbbb39bc9bfa6c0cb0d4721

Comment: Ok I'll accept it for now because that's what I suspected, but I can't find any reference saying that this is actually valid for the docker hub. It's the documentation for the docker registry. I know that docker hub act like a registry, but I'd like to see it written somewhere

Comment: I got this answer from the docker guys. My other question that you answered about docker API was already done in their forum, and it was the answer they gave me. not sure if it is public: https://support.docker.com/hc/en-us/restricted?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.docker.com%2Fhc%2Fen-us%2Frequests%2F16575

Comment: Linked docs now seem to describe a totally different API to what the gists are using: e.g. `/v2/$ORG/$REPO/tags/list?n=10` returning `{tags:string[],...}` instead of `/v2/repostitory/$ORG/$REPO/tags/?page_size=10` returning `{results:{name:string,...}[]}`. Whatever, gist examples still work.

Comment: I am finding the same inconsistencies - which one is the Docker Hub registry API?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use Docker Hub API v2 for private repo in order to get list of all tags, example is here if anyone needs it:

- https://gist.github.com/alexanderilyin/8cf68f85b922a7f1757ae3a74640d48a